# Expression to hide subreport in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services

The following expression to show/hide subreport is not working.

```
=iif((DateAdd("d", 45, Fields!actualclosingdate.Value) > Today()), True, False)
```

Any suggestions, alternatives, or advice will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is there any error or warning about expression ?

Answer (score 0):

Please try to put the subreport into a rectangle and set the visibility of that rectangle.

Comment: Why there is need to put the sub report in rectangle when subreport has Visibility property where you can set the expression ?

Answer (score 0):

Most of the times issue with the `SSRS` value matching expressions are the data types of the values that creates the problems or undesired result. In your case your `actualclosingdate` field might be coming as the string so you need to make sure that it is convert back to the Date before adding days to it. For that matter always right your expressions in `SSRS` using type conversion so your expression can be on safer side.

And I am also assuming that your requirement is,

If the actual closing date +45 days is greater than `Today` then hide the report and if not then show.

SO **Subreport->RightClick->Proprties->Visibility->Show/hide based on expression**

```
=IIF((DateAdd("d", 45,CDate(Fields!actualclosingdate.Value)) > Today()), True, False)
```